# ssh wget connection refused

Tags: ssh, wget

I have 3 servers with WHM and I want to transfer some files from server1 and server2 to server3.

I did a backup of files on server1, database backup on server2 and now I need to get files from server1 and server2 to server3 using SSH.

I login to server3 using SSH and I use wget command to get files from server1 - works fine. When I try to use wget to get files from server2 I get "connection refused" error.

What could be a problem?

EDIT: I used online tool to check is ports are opened at server2 and I found that ports 22 and 80 are closed. This is very strange because when I login to WHM and check firewall configuration both ports are listed under TCP_IN, TCP_OUT, UDP_IN and UDP_OUT.

How can I open ports with ssh or whm?

I also did this check for server1 and ports are opened, so I guess this is why I can't get files from server2, because ports 22 and 80 are closed.

Here's the output of netstat -lan | egrep LISTEN

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2095            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:783           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2096            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 208.85.2.142:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 208.85.2.141:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 208.85.2.140:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 208.85.2.139:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 208.85.2.138:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2082            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2083            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2086            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2087            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:783                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::465                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::995                  :::*                    LISTEN
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     238522   /var/cpanel/php-fpm/cpanelphpmyadmin/sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1051941  /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14357    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743720   /var/run/dovecot/stats
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743726   /var/run/dovecot/ssl-params
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1329315  /usr/local/cpanel/var/cpauthd.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1329316  /usr/local/cpanel/var/cpdoveauthd.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1318256  /var/cpanel/userhomes/cpanelconnecttrack/p0f.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743728   /var/run/dovecot/login/ssl-params
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743732   /var/run/dovecot/replicator
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743736   /var/run/dovecot/replication-notify
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     247837   /var/clamd
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743739   /var/run/dovecot/login/pop3
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1053251  /var/run/cphulkd.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743747   /var/run/dovecot/log-errors
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743751   /var/run/dovecot/lmtp
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743755   /var/run/dovecot/ipc
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743757   /var/run/dovecot/login/ipc-proxy
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     25680    /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743761   /var/run/dovecot/indexer-worker
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     962684   /var/cpanel/php-fpm/operationsports/sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743765   /var/run/dovecot/indexer
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743767   /var/run/dovecot/login/imap
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     753466   /var/cpanel/dnsadmin/sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12377    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743771   /var/run/dovecot/imap-master
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12380    /var/run/rpcbind.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743775   /var/run/dovecot/imap-urlauth-worker
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743777   /var/run/dovecot/token-login/imap-urlauth
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743781   /var/run/dovecot/imap-urlauth
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743789   /var/run/dovecot/imap-hibernate
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743793   /var/run/dovecot/doveadm-server
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743797   /var/run/dovecot/dns-client
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743801   /var/run/dovecot/director-admin
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743805   /var/run/dovecot/dict
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743809   /var/run/dovecot/dict-async
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743813   /var/run/dovecot/config
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743815   /var/run/dovecot/login/login
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743817   /var/run/dovecot/token-login/tokenlogin
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743821   /var/run/dovecot/auth-login
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743825   /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743829   /var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743833   /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     221082   /var/run/nscd/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743837   /var/run/dovecot/auth-worker
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743841   /var/run/dovecot/anvil
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     25763    /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743845   /var/run/dovecot/anvil-auth-penalty
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743849   /var/run/dovecot/quota-status
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     743852   /var/run/dovecot/master
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1313199  /etc/apache2/run/cgid_sock.28821
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     671672   /var/run/ftpd.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1329314  /usr/local/cpanel/var/cpwrapd.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     238524   /var/cpanel/php-fpm/cpanelphppgadmin/sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     238526   /var/cpanel/php-fpm/cpanelroundcube/sock
```

EDIT: I checked /etc/ssh/sshd_config on server1 and server2 and everything is the same, but for some reason server2 is refusing connection.

Comment: If you are able to login with ssh, it should work scp too: scp user@host:/path/to/file /destination/file

Comment: I get same error [root@osdb3 ~]# scp root@xx.xx.xx.xx:/vBulletin.sql /vBulletin.sql
ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: Connection refused

Comment: May be the SSH server denies password-based login for root. You should try accessing the server with a user different than root. Otherwise if you have sudo access to the server you can set "PermitRootLogin yes" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config and restart sshd daemon.

Comment: I opened sshd_config file and uncommented "PermitRootLogin yes", then in command line I typed "service sshd restart"...if this is a correct command than this didn't fixed a problem as I get same error.

Comment: Check `/etc/hosts.deny`, also

Comment: hosts.deny is empty

Comment: Could it be a firewall issue (ports 22 and 80 not allowed for inbound connexions)?

Comment: I don't know what it was as I'm begginer with SSH, but somehow I managed to open port 22 and to connect to server2.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. I used online tool to check for opened ports and ports 22 and 80 were closed and that is why connection was refused.

Thank you all for help.